# Linear Algebra determinant and rank relation

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, inverse

True or False?

> If the determinant of a $4 \times 4$ matrix $A$ is $4$
>    then its rank must be $4$.

Is it false or true?

My guess is true, because the matrix $A$ is invertible.

But there is any counter-example?

Please help me.

Comment: Why don't you believe in your statement?

Comment: DId I get it right? I was just making sure, because I have no answer for that.

Comment: Are you simply being tripped up by the fact they chose the specific value of 4 everywhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're absolutely correct. The point of mathematical proof is that you don't need to go looking for counterexamples once you've found the proof. Beforehand that's very reasonable, but once you're done you're done.

Determinant 4 is nonzero $\implies$ invertible $\implies$ full rank.

Each of these is a standard proposition in linear algebra.

Answer (score 2):

If it is invertible, it is full-rank. The rank is the dimension of $\operatorname{Im} A$.

Comment: So that is true right?

Comment: Yes. Why are you so unsure of your answer?

Comment: @ClementC., maybe the OP does not have some knowledge on linear transformation.